# Netbeans : JavaFX components are missing

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, openjfx

I'm beginning with Java and I've tried installing JavaFX on Netbeans, but I can't run anything because I get an error saying that JavaFX runtime components are missing.

I followed the instructions on the OpenJFX website and everything seemed to work fine.

I'm using Java 13 on Netbeans 11.1

Any idea where the problem is ?

Comment: You are likely using JDK 11+ and JavaFX is no longer included with it.

Comment: I think the old Netbeans JavaFX project structure used ant (this may be totally wrong). I am guessing that's the problem. The instructions you followed on the OpenJFX site are now the correct steps to set up a JavaFX project in Netbeans at the moment.

Comment: make sure you have added the VM options as described under Nr. 5 `--module-path "\path\to\javafx-sdk-12\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no question was asked.

Comment: You followed the instructions and it worked? Why do you post this as a question, if you already got it working?

Comment: @NobodyIsPerfect Yep that's why I'm trying to use OpenJFX

Comment: @fabian I followed the instructions to setup OpenJFX (which went as expected) but it's not working.

Comment: @Sedrick Well my question is "how to get it to work ?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing some VM options

```
--module-path "\path\to\javafx-sdk-12\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

Many thanks @Eritrean !

Comment: Please include those options in this answer.